# Move Menu minipanels DOM location

Tags: routes, panels, theming

I am trying to create a Menu-minipanel which will appear directly below the horizontal header menu, and push the content below down.

I have set the menu positioning to static so that it sits within the page structure, but that renders it at the bottom of the page when triggered (which is where it is put by default, and usually repositioned from there outside of the page structure).

Among the Menu mini-panels options there is a field labelled:

> "Allows control over where within the page's DOM structure the
>   minipanel will be inserted. This defaults to $(document.body), i.e. at
>   the end of the page's content."

but I have absolutely no idea how to manipulate this, and cannot find any documentation which makes this clear.

DOM is something I simply don't have a clue about, and I feel like I am so close to the answer, but my own knowledge seems to have run out!

Any guidance would be so appreciated!

Comment: Thats basically saying it gives you the option to place the panel where you want to. Have you event tried it?

Comment: Looks like I cant answer my own question as a relatively new user, but through a bit of experimentation I found that the reference to the default value of '$(document.body)' was what confused me - it turns out that just by adding a standard css selector to that field moved the menu.

Its always when one asks for help that inspiration strikes!

Thanks for reading Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, though a bit of experimentation I found that the language

> "Allows control over where within the page's DOM structure the
>   minipanel will be inserted. This defaults to $(document.body), i.e. at
>   the end of the page's content."

Was what confused me - it turns out that just by adding a standard css selector to that field moved the menu.